# Function that satisfies the given (x,y) values

Tags: functions, interpolation

I am trying to come up with a function that (approximately) satisfies these $(x,y)$ values.

$(2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 6), (9, 5), (10, 4), (11, 3), (12, 2), (13, 1), (14, 2), (15, 3), (16, 4), (17, 5), (18, 6), (19, 7), (20, 8), (21, 7), (22, 6), (23, 5), (24, 4), (25, 3), (26, 2), (27, 3), (28, 4), (29, 5), (30, 6), (31, 7), (32, 8), \text {(other, anything)}$

I want to create a continuous function $f(x)$ which takes $x$ as input and outputs the corresponding $y$ value as given above. If possible, I don't want a piecewise function.

Is there a technique to do this?

Comment: How can it be continuous if you want $f$ to vanish on the "other" points? For every integer k that you posted above, $f$ will vanish at all points arbitrarily close to $k$, but be positive at $k$, hence being discontinuous at $k$.

Comment: I think I worded that in the wrong way, I meant to say that I don't care about the value at other points. Fixed.

Comment: It's obviously possible piecewise, but off the bat, I can't think of a way to do it with writing $f$ as a single expression. Note though, that given a continuous function $f$ whose graph passes through those points you listed (as I just said, such an $f$ exists), you can approximate $f$ to whatever degree of accuracy you wish using a polynomial.

Comment: If you don't want it piecewise, there _is_ a polynomial for the job [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial ].  It won't be pretty...

Comment: There are many methods for doing so. If you know the general form of the function you could adjust the parameters using  the minimum squares method. A nice method for joining points like that where you only want to know the values inside this range is the many variations of splines methods. You can also use polinomials and force it to pass on those points. Each technique has its advantages and disadvantages, without giving it much thought cubic splines sounds like a good one, but take a further look at these other methods.

Answer (score 1):

This function isn't exactly pretty, and it's not in the form $y=f(x)$ (I'm not even sure it's possible to put it in that form), but at the very least, it's continuous and passes through all the points you specified.

$$\frac{y-\frac{x}{13}}{\left(\sqrt{y-\frac{x}{13}}\right)^2}(7-|x-7|-y)(8-|x-20|-y)(9-|x-33|-y)=0$$

I made it by first finding the equation of the first peak, which is $y=7-|x-7|$, and then superimposing it with the graphs of the other two peaks; that's what the three sets of parentheses are for. The fraction in front limits the range of the graph to all points where $y\ge x/13$, since $y=x/13$ is the line connecting the two lowest points you provided. Here's what it looks like (with the function in blue and your points in green):

[image]

Interesting sidenote/tangent: if you wanted to generalize that function to continue the pattern that your points make, this should do the trick, where $i$ and $j$ are the $y$-coordinates of the first and last peaks, respectively:

$$\frac{y-\frac{x}{13}}{\left(\sqrt{y-\frac{x}{13}}\right)^2}\prod_{n=i}^j(n-|x-13n+84|-y)=0$$

It's equivalent to the above function and graph when $i=7$ and $j=9$. For example, here's what it looks like when $i=4$ and $j=12$:

[image]

Here's a link to the Desmos page I used to make those functions: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8vcxwsaebq